# Unpleasant small movement in overlapped expanding div

Tags: html, css, overlap

When you open it, click in the color aqua div, then make a hover in the first box and click where it says "CLICK ME". You'll see that when the appearing div reaches the border of the windows, there is a little movement in the top border, which is very annoying. I tried a lot of things but i wasn't able to remove it. Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

```css
/* ////// INITIAL RESET AND CONFIGURATIONS ////// */

html {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  /* Hide the other pages */
}
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  /*height: 100%;    Also works 100vh (View percentage lenght) */
  overflow: hidden;
}
ul {
  list-style: none;
  text-align: center;
}
a {
  display: block;
  border: none;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  cursor: default;
}
/*================================== PAGE SLIDE TRANSITION ==================================*/

/* Basic Style/Positioning for all Pages */

.pages,
.page,
.page .backbutton,
.page .nextbutton {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.page .backbutton,
.page .nextbutton {
  height: 10%;
  background-color: red;
  z-index: 1;
}
.page .backbutton {
  top: 0%;
}
.page .nextbutton {
  top: 90%;
  background-color: aqua;
}
/* Pages */

#i2 {
  top: 100%;
}
#i3 {
  top: 200%;
}
/* Slide Effect */

.pages {
  -webkit-transition: top 0.8s;
  -moz-transition: top 0.8s;
  -o-transition: top 0.8s;
  -ms-transition: top 0.8s;
  transition: top 0.8s;
}
#a1:target .pages {
  top: 0%;
}
#a2:target .pages {
  top: -100%;
}
#a3:target .pages {
  top: -200%;
}
#i1 {
  background-color: #fff;
}
#i2 {
  background-color: #bbb;
}
#i3 {
  background-color: #777;
}
/*================================== PAGE ONE ==================================*/

/* ////// ELEMENT'S POSITION ////// */

#i1 {
  background-color: bisque;
  /*position:relative;     stacking context */
}
/* ////// HOVER ////// */

.menu li a:hover {
  background: teal;
  visibility: visible;
}
#i1 .menu li a:hover + .image {
  top: 0;
}
#i1 .menu li a {
  z-index: 3;
  position: relative;
}
#i1 li .image {
  position: absolute;
  width: 17.5%;
  padding: 0px;
  border: 0px #999999 solid;
  margin: 0px;
  height: 100%;
  transition: 0.8s;
  top: -50%;
}
#i1 .image1 {
  background-color: grey;
  left: 10%;
}
#i1 .image2 {
  background-color: #777777;
  left: 27.5%;
}
#i1 .image3 {
  background-color: #555555;
  left: 45%;
}
#i1 .image4 {
  background-color: #333333;
  left: 62.5%;
}
/* ////// ICON ////// */

[data-icon]:before {
  /* Allows to show the icons */
  font-family: 'icomoon';
  content: attr(data-icon);
  speak: none;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-variant: normal;
  text-transform: none;
  line-height: 1;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}
.icon:before {
  /* Shows the icon */
  float: left;
  content: '\e60e';
  font-family: 'icomoon';
  speak: none;
  color: red;
  font-size: 50px;
}
#button_menu {
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
}
label {
  position: absolute;
  float: left;
  top: 75%;
  left: 3%;
  border: 1px green solid;
}
#button_menu + label {
  cursor: pointer;
}
/* ////// MENU OPTION's TRANSITIONS ////// */

.menu {
  list-style: none;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 70%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  margin-top: 80vh;
  margin-left: 10%;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid #FF0000;
}
li.option {
  float: left;
  display: inline-block;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0px 55px 0px 55px;
  width: 25%;
  margin: 0;
  margin-top: 20px;
  background: yellow;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: .5s;
}
#button_menu:checked ~ .menu a {
  cursor: pointer;
}
#button_menu:checked ~ .menu .option {
  margin-top: 0px;
  opacity: 1;
}
li.option:first-child {
  transition-delay: .6s;
}
li.option:nth-child(2) {
  transition-delay: .4s;
}
li.option:nth-child(3) {
  transition-delay: .2s;
}
li.option:last-child {
  transition-delay: 0s;
}
#button_menu:checked ~ .menu li.option:first-child {
  transition-delay: 0s;
}
#button_menu:checked ~ .menu li.option:nth-child(2) {
  transition-delay: .2s;
}
#button_menu:checked ~ .menu li.option:nth-child(3) {
  transition-delay: .4s;
}
#button_menu:checked ~ .menu li.option:last-child {
  transition-delay: .6s;
}
/*================================== PAGE TWO ==================================*/

h1,
p {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  transform: scale(10);
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0.1s;
}
.overlay {
  display: block;
  100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#ov .overlay_open {
  position: absolute;
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transform: scale(0.9);
  transform: scale(0.9|);
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.2s, opacity 0.2s, visibility 0s 0.2s;
  transition: transform 0.2s, opacity 0.2s, visibility 0s 0.2s;
  background-color: chocolate;
  z-index: 2;
}
/* ////// CENTERING THE PICTURES //////*/

.container {
  /*occupes all the screen and hide the divs bigger than it*/
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.center {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
}
/*div centers in the middle of its parent, with 0
                                                   height and with (just a dot)*/

.center-container {
  position: absolute;
  left: -2500px;
  top: -2500px;
  /*move it left and top to be centered exactly in the middle from the center                                   doth*/
  width: 5000px;
  height: 5000px;
  line-height: 5000px;
  text-align: center;
  /*centers horizontally the pictures*/
  overflow: hidden;
}
.dyn-box {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  line-height: 100%;
}
/*-----------------***-----------------*/

.box {
  float: left;
  width: 130px;
  height: 130px;
  margin: 10px;
  border: 5px black solid;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.b4 {
  clear: both;
}
.picture {
  position: absolute;
  width: 130px;
  height: 130px;
  background-color: beige;
}
.mask {
  position: absolute;
  width: 130px;
  height: 130px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: coral;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0.1s;
}
.box .mask:hover {
  opacity: 0.4;
}
.box .mask:hover h1 {
  transform: scale(1);
  opacity: 1;
}
.box .mask:hover p {
  transform: scale(1);
  opacity: 1;
  transition-delay: .2s;
}
#ov:target .overlay_open {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 0.8;
  -webkit-transform: scale(1);
  transform: scale(1);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="rock_page.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="icons_files/style.css">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.11.2.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
  <title>Rock n' Roll</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="a1">
    <div id="a2">
      <div id="a3">
        <div class="pages">

          <!-- Second Page #a1 -->
          <div id="i1" class="page">
            <input type="checkbox" name="button_menu" id="button_menu" />
            <label for="button_menu" class="icon"></label>
            <!--This also works for the icon instead of the CSS code
                 <span aria-hidden="true" data-icon="&#xe60e;" class="down-arrow">-->
            <ul class="menu">
              <li class="option"><a href="#">Link 1</a>
                <div class="image image1"></div>
              </li>
              <li class="option"><a href="#">Link 2</a>
                <div class="image image2"></div>
              </li>
              <li class="option"><a href="#">Link 3</a>
                <div class="image image3"></div>
              </li>
              <li class="option"><a href="#">Link 4</a>
                <div class="image image4"></div>
              </li>
            </ul>
            <a href="#a2" class="nextbutton"></a>
          </div>

          <!-- Second Page #a2 -->
          <div id="i2" class="page">
            <a href="#a1" class="backbutton"></a>
            <a href="#a3" class="nextbutton"></a>
            <div class="container">
              <div class="center">
                <div class="center-container">
                  <span class="dyn-box">
                                        <div class="box b1">
                                            <div class="picture"></div>
                                            <div class="mask">
                                                <h1>Text</h1>
                                                <p>Lore ipsum facto lore impsum facto</p>
                                                <a href="#ov" class="link">CLICK ME</a>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="box b2">
                                            <div class="picture"></div>
                                                <div class="mask">
                                                    <h1>Text</h1>
                                                    <p>Lore ipsum facto lore impsum facto</p>
                                                </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="box b3">
                                            <div class="picture"></div>
                                                <div class="mask">
                                                    <h1>Text</h1>
                                                    <p>Lore ipsum facto lore impsum facto</p>
                                                </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="box b4">
                                            <div class="picture"></div>
                                                <div class="mask">
                                                    <h1>Text</h1>
                                                    <p>Lore ipsum facto lore impsum facto</p>
                                                </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="box b5">
                                            <div class="picture"></div>
                                                <div class="mask">
                                                    <h1>Text</h1>
                                                    <p>Lore ipsum facto lore impsum facto</p>
                                                </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="box b6">
                                        <div class="picture"></div>
                                            <div class="mask">
                                                <h1>Text</h1>
                                                <p>Lore ipsum facto lore impsum facto</p>
                                            </div>
                                    </div>
                                    </span>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div id="ov" class="overlay">
              <div class="overlay_open">
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <!-- Third Page #a3 -->
          <div id="i3" class="page">
            <a href="#a2" class="backbutton"></a>
          </div>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

This simplified version works exactly like i want, and the transition is more fluid too.

```css
body, .container { margin: 0; padding: 0;}

a {position: absolute}

.container .overlay {
    position: fixed;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    visibility: hidden;
 opacity: 0;
 -webkit-transform: scale(0.9);
 transform: scale(0.9);
 -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.2s, opacity 0.2s, visibility 0s 0.2s;
 transition: transform 0.2s, opacity 0.2s, visibility 0s 0.2s;
    background-color: chocolate;
    z-index: 2;
}

#c:target .overlay {
    visibility: visible;
 opacity: 0.8;
 -webkit-transform: scale(1);
 transform: scale(1);
 -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.4s, opacity 0.4s;
 transition: transform 0.4s, opacity 0.4s;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div id="c" class="container">
        <a href="#c">OPEN</a>
        <div class="overlay">
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Why do you think the second one is more fluid and works better than the one you have?

Comment: The second one works better because it doesnt have that little movement in the top border at the end of the transition, and is more fluid because in the first one the transition isnt working fine, practically jumps from the start to the end. Run both of the codes and i think you'll see the difference inmediately.

Comment: To be more specific, I'm asking you what the difference in code between yours and the one that works better is. You have the finished product so theoretically you should be able to replicate it. If it's not working for you, it's probably because you have something different from the final product.

Comment: The second one is just a copy from the part of the first one, which is supposed to do exactly the same, but it doesnt. I think the problem could be in how that code interactues with the rest of the code, specially with how is positioned with the divs in the second page (of the first code), but im not really sure, andi cant figure out how to fix it.

Comment: Fact: they are not the same code. You gave a different position than the one that works.

Comment: Yes, it's true, i forgot to actualize the code. But if you change the fixed position to absolute position, the effects is the same. Here is a pen with the position changed, and as you can see there is no difference: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gbJBmb (by the way, thanks for the patience).

Comment: Here is a more complete pen http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Ggbjox wich is identical to the second page, but it doesn't have the little movement in the top border when the appearing div reaches it. When I copy this code in the original code, the problem remains. And here it is the original code actualized with the new code http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wBLzGQ.

Comment: Remove your overlay, you'll notice the reason for the jittery movement is because of your anchor and probably the script that's making it "scroll to" a certain point. This jittery issues has nothing to do with the overlay but more to do with the anchor.

Comment: I'm not following you very well. If I remove the overlay, how i would able to see the efect? (I tried and nothing happened). Here's a new pen http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jEjBYN. I moved the second page to the first one, and now works perfectly fine, so I think the problem is in the second page, but i can't figure out exactly where it is.

Comment: Seems like transitioning top property on your `.pages` class is the problem. When commented out and put inside `#aX:target .pages` selector it works fine, take a look: http://codepen.io/teodragovic/pen/LEKLWE?editors=110